# How can I get video of specific model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

I want to display videos for each model in my table, where to define they are connected by their ids?

In my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $model_video = NewModelVideos::all();

    return view('admin.model_new_videos.index')
        ->with('models', $models)
        ->with('model_video', $model_video);
}
```

in my Model:

```
class NewModelVideos extends Model
{
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\NewModels\NewModel', 'model_id');
    }
}
```

```
class NewModel extends Model
{
    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\NewModels\NewModelVideos', 'model_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and View:

```
@foreach($model_video as $model)                                    
    {{ $model->video }}     
@endforeach
```

Comment: What errors do you get? (It's `->videos`, not `->video`)

Comment: So you want to display all videos and the `NewModel` related to them or do you want to show all `NewModel`s and the videos attached to them?

Comment: If I make {{ $model->videos }} I don't get any video, and if I do {{ $model->video }}  I get every video, not only from specific model.

Comment: I want  to show all NewModels and the videos attached to them

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $model_video = NewModelVideos::all();
    $models = NewModel::all();

    return view('admin.model_new_videos.index')
        ->with('models', $models)
        ->with('model_video', $model_video);
}
```

and blade:

```
@foreach($models as $model)                                    
    {{ $model->videos }}    //get videos
@endforeach

@foreach($model_video as $video)                                    
    {{ $video->model }}    //get model
@endforeach
```

Comment: Now I get every video for every model, no matter if they don't have that video, it is not based on their ID. How can I get that for specific model I get his video?

Comment: and what about Model? it still not returning specific videos from specific model

Comment: @hecc12 explain with an example

Comment: I have Model1 who has video1 and video2. Model2 has video3. I want to display each model with their videos. And now I am getting Model1 with video1,video2,video3. And also Model2 with video1,video2,video3.

Comment: @hecc12 you make a mistake in define relations method or table.

Comment: that is why I ask for help because I cannot see it

Comment: should you show to us your models and migrations @hecc12

Comment: i edited in my code. you can check . i don't use migrations

Comment: @hecc12 i need more information about your code. because there are many reasons for this problem. you can send me an email (mehdi.samirakh68@gamil.com). I'd be glad if I can help